# if value is undefined in template angular 2/5

Tags: angular

I have a drop down and I want to select the first option if variable `user.gender` is undefined.

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="gender" [(ngModel)]="user.gender">
  <option [attr.selected]="user.gender == undefined ? true : null ">Select</option>
  <option value="1" >Male</option>
  <option value="0" >Female</option>
</select>
```

One not so clean approach which works is setting the first options `value="undefined"`. Is there any better way?

Comment: How about setting value="" in UI and in ts file set user.gender =  user.gender? "" : user.gender;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you should decide you use template driven form, or reactive form (there is no point to use NgModel two-way binding if you already control your input with `formControlName="gender"` because you can update value via that control)

In template driven way, you can do so:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.gender">
  <option value=undefined>Select</option>
  <option value="1" >Male</option>
  <option value="0" >Female</option>
</select>
```

Component:

`user = { gender: undefined }`

Answer (score 1):

You should set the default value in the controller or you can do it in a view like with `<option selected>Male</option>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. In .ts declare `start = null`.
2. In ngOnInit write  `ngOnInit() {user.gender=start}`.
3. In .html file

```html
<select class="form-control" formControlName="gender" [(ngModel)]="user.gender">
  <option disabled [value]="start" selected="true">Select</option>
  <option [value]="1" value="1" >Male</option>
  <option [value]="0" >Female</option>
</select>
```